# is their a way to prevent php gzuncompress data error Severity: Warning

Tags: php, gzip

is their a way to prevent php gzuncompress() function's data error **Severity: Warning**

so if an **data error** occurred due to wrong data input

it will just return **false** or null

instead of an **Severity: Warning** as follow :

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: gzuncompress(): data error

i don't want to off warning for all other by turning of the error reporting

i have tried

```
try {
        $result=  gzuncompress($crypt) ;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
         $result=$ex;
    }
```

expecting that it will not show and store the massage .

This is not exactly what i am looking for as i want to catch the event and do an step
but any how right now i have solve it using @

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already found out, `gzuncompress` doesn't throw an exception; so you can do something like this:

```
$result = @gzuncompress($data);
if ($result === false) {
    // do something related to error here
}
```

But if you really wanted to throw exceptions during such warnings, as per your desired code snippet, you could define a global error handler with:

```
set_error_handler(
    function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
        if ($errno == E_WARNING && $errstr == 'gzuncompress(): data error') {
            throw new MyGzException($errstr);
        }
    }
);
```

And then in your code you would say:

```
try {
    $result = @gzuncompress($data);
} catch (MyGzException $e) {
    $result = $e;
}
```

However, again, this is a global handler and there could be a couple of problems with this:

- side effects to other parts of the applications that might not expect an exception in these cases
- your application might already provide its own error handler, which you would be overriding

So, only do this if you are aware of full implications and side effects of using a global error handler.

Comment: thanks the middle one exactly what i was looking for